# How do I change LUKS backend to OpenSSL?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, disk-encryption, configuration, luks

I know there is a way to do it, but I don't know how to do it: the default backend for LUKS is `libgcrypt` and I want to test it with the `openssl` cryptographic library.

I was told that there is a configuration file to edit but I didn't find it.

UPDATE:

On most distros the option `--with-crypto_backend=openssl` won't compile without installing `libssl-dev` (signaled as dependence) AND `pkg-config` (NOT signaled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compile-time option, not a run-time option.  If you run `./configure --help` on the `cryptsetup` source code, it'll reveal that `--with-crypto_backend=openssl` will do what you want.

Comment: I have to correct me: I could compile with openssl, but comparing the values of the iteration count for the passhprase, there is no difference between openssl and libgcrypt. And this appear strange to me. I tested it on arch, Debian Jessie, Ubuntu 15.01, Lubuntu 15.01. On arch I can see a 50% positive difference for openssl. It seems like it is not using a different backend

Comment: If you're trying to replace your distro's `cryptsetup` with a custom-built one, you need to make sure you're running the one you think you are.  This varies a bit from distro to distro, and is beyond the scope of infosec.se.